# Subset character columns from a data frame of characters and numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame composed of numeric and non-numeric columns.

I would like to extract (subset) only the non-numeric columns, so the character ones. While I was able to subset the numeric columns using the string: `sub_num = x[sapply(x, is.numeric)]`, I'm not able to do the opposite using the `is.character` form. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe you can post at least a subset of `str(x)` for us. That way we could see what is going on.

Comment: As a first guess: Might it be possible that your character columns in fact are factors?

Comment: Hi Thilo, sorry for not posting the str(x). As you correctly suggest me, the character columns are factors!! I wrongly didn't check it before. I tried to run the strings you posted and it works perfectly!! Thank you very much!!!!!!

Comment: In case it works as expected you can accept one of the answers you got, meaning either Tyler's or mine. You can do that by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. This way further visitors to the question can see what worked for your problem. Furthermore, the person giving the answer gains a small amount of reputation (which gives you certain privileges over time, but that is something for the Stackoverflow-FAQs).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I did a short try about my idea.

I could confirm that the following code snippet is working:

```
str(d)
 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
  $ a: int  1 2 3 4 5
  $ b: chr  "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
  $ c: Factor w/ 1 level "b": 1 1 1 1 1


# Get all character columns
d[, sapply(d, class) == 'character']

# Or, for factors, which might be likely:
d[, sapply(d, class) == 'factor']

# If you want to get both factors and characters use
d[, sapply(d, class) %in% c('character', 'factor')]
```

Using the correct class, your `sapply`-approach should work as well, at least as long as you insert the missing `,` before the `sapply` function.

The approach using `!is.numeric` does not scale very well if you have classes that do not belong in the group `numeric, factor, character` (one I use very often is `POSIXct`, for example)

Comment: With R, stats and carpentry (my father's trade) it's about the best tool for the job.  I agree `!is.numeric` doesn't work as well for `POSIXct` etc. but per the OPs parameters the `!is.numeric` approach is fastest and slightly less typing.

Answer (score 11):

If you are trying to select only character columns, this can be done with `dplyr::select_if()` and `is.character()`. Using the `dplyr::starwars` sample data as an example:

```
library(dplyr)
starwars %>% 
  select_if(is.character) %>% 
  head(2)
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  name           hair_color skin_color eye_color gender homeworld species
  <chr>          <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr>  <chr>     <chr>  
1 Luke Skywalker blond      fair       blue      male   Tatooine  Human  
2 C-3PO          NA         gold       yellow    NA     Tatooine  Droid
```

Or if you are trying to negate a certain column type, note that the syntax is slightly different:

```
starwars %>%  
  select_if(~!is.numeric(.)) %>% 
  head(2)

# A tibble: 2 x 10
    name           hair_color skin_color eye_color gender homeworld species films     vehicles  starships
    <chr>          <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr>  <chr>     <chr>   <list>    <list>    <list>   
  1 Luke Skywalker blond      fair       blue      male   Tatooine  Human   <chr [5]> <chr [2]> <chr [2]>
  2 C-3PO          NA         gold       yellow    NA     Tatooine  Droid   <chr [6]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]>
```

Comment: As of dplyr 1.0.0 *_if functions and friends have been superseded. Below solution is recommended.  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62154976/6090977

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
x[sapply(x, function(x) !is.numeric(x))]
```

As it will pull anything not numeric so factors and character.

**EDIT:**

```
x <- data.frame(a=runif(10), b=1:10, c=letters[1:10], 
    d=as.factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each=5)), 
    e=as.Date(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by="month", length.out=10)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# > str(x)
# 'data.frame':   10 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ a: num  0.814 0.372 0.732 0.522 0.626 ...
#  $ b: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  $ c: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#  $ d: Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
#  $ e: Date, format: "2000-01-01" "2000-02-01" ...

x[sapply(x, function(x) !is.numeric(x))]
```

Comment: Hi Tyler! I tried your code, but it does not work because I wrongly didn't check that the columns are factors instead of characters. But..apart from this thank you for your help!

Comment: That's not the problem then as this will find both character and factors and actually anything not numeric, that was the issue Thilo and I were discussing.  See my edits.

Answer (score 3):

As per most recent `dplyr` updates:

```
starwars %>% 
  select(where(is.character))
```

You can switch `is.character` to `is.numeric`/ `is.factor` and so on.

Another way would be to use `keep` or `discard` functions from `purrr` package:

```
starwars %>% 
  purrr::keep(~is.character(.)) 

starwars %>% 
  purrr::discard(~!is.character(.))
```

Answer (score 1):

The other previous answers are not that clear. So I post this approach. To get the names of the character columns, you can do the following thing:

```
chrs <- sapply(df_data, is.character)
chrCols <- names(df_data[, chrs])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the @ Tyler Example

```
x <- data.frame(a=runif(10), b=1:10, c=letters[1:10], 
    d=as.factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each=5)), 
    e=as.Date(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by="month", length.out=10)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

In Base R

base::Filter(Negate(is.numeric),x)



   c d          e
1  a A 2000-01-01
2  b A 2000-02-01
3  c A 2000-03-01
4  d A 2000-04-01
5  e A 2000-05-01
6  f B 2000-06-01
7  g B 2000-07-01
8  h B 2000-08-01
9  i B 2000-09-01
10 j B 2000-10-01
```